# How to get the content of Iframe which is in another jsp page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an jsp(1.jsp) page which has an another jsp page(2.jsp) as an Iframe. Now if i want to get the value of Iframe in Java script of 2.jsp i am getting null. can any one please tell me how can I get the value of the Iframe in the 2.jsp.

Comment: Here in 2.jsp i am getting Ifrmae value as null.

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe src is of the same domain/subdomain of the parent (i.e. `www.website.com` or simply `my.ip.address.here` (same port)), you can retrieve the contents of the iframe via jQuery's `$('#amr iframe').contents()`.

Alternatively you can use pure javascript via `myIframeElement.contentWindow.document` (and then, for example, `getElementById` like you'd normally do with `window`)

Comment: Hi Jack i am using only pure java script.

Comment: Added pure javascript alternative :)

Comment: if i use 'var iframe = document.getElementById('Contact1');' I am geeting the iframe value null so i dint able to get inner doc. I think because 2.jsp is an Iframe of 1.jsp , getting the value of iframe of 1.jso in 2.jsp giving me null.

Comment: Edited, it's not content, but contentWindow (sorry!). In any case if you get `null` calling `document.getElementById('Contact1');` it means the element has not been loaded in the DOM yet. Have you tried wrapping all your code in `window.addEventListener('load', function () {...});`?

Comment: not working still i am getting null after using window.addEventListener('load', function () {...});

Comment: Well, that's really strange... if you still have `null` you should check your script's workflow. Is this iframe inside another iframe? If yes and you're executing the code from the outer iframe's parent context, you'll never be able to see it. You have to execute the code in the same document context the iframe is in.

After that, you'd be sure the iframe's content has loaded before trying to access it (obviously)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78068/discussion-between-mohammad-gouse-and-jack).